# How do I download a Maven artifact at the command line without using dependency:get or maven-download-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

I'd like to download an artifact and its dependencies at the command line. I.e.

```
mvn [some plugin]:[goal] -DartifactId=[artifactId] -DgroupId=[groupId] -Dversion=[version]
```

I've tried mvn dependency:get but this seems to require a list of remote repositories. I want mvn to use what's already specified in settings.xml

I've also tried the [maven-download-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-download-plugin/) but this doesn't seem to work properly (it tried downloading xerces-impl as a transitive dependency of ant and failed to resolve it. Neither xerces-impl nor ant are dependencies of my artifact).

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using the latest version of dependency:get, it works for me

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DartifactId=[artifactId] -DgroupId=[groupId] -Dversion=[version]
```

works for me

Comment: Thanks mate. Looks like the local repo is populated with deps and the named artifact is saved to the specified -Ddest=[file]

Comment: If you need to copy the resolved artifact to some location outside your local maven repository (~/.m2/repository), use maven-dependency-plugin:copy goal instead of maven-dependency-plugin:get (deprecated)

Src: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html#destination

Comment: Pedantic point, but to use the latest version, specify LATEST, rather than a specific version; e.g. mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:LATEST:get

Answer (score 46):

The `copy` goal is more appropriate here and it lets you specify an output directory as well (which is deprecated in the `get` goal):

`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version[:packaging][:classifier] -DoutputDirectory=[target] -Dmdep.useBaseVersion=true`

`mdep.useBaseVersion=true` will remove timestamps from snapshot builds.

Answer (score 4):

Example to download version 6.9.4 of TestNG to your local ~/.m2/repository (uses maven-dependency-plugin:get):

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:RELEASE:get \
-Dartifact=org.testng:testng:6.9.4:jar
```

Example to download version 4.11 of JUnit to your current working directory (uses maven-dependency-plugin:copy):

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:RELEASE:copy \
-Dartifact=junit:junit:4.11:jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create a simple pom with the appropriate dependencies and do mvn clean package on that mini project...

Comment: Thanks but I want to perform the download in a single command, to be included in a script.

Comment: If you have a script just generate the pom via script and call mvn -f generate-pom.xml on it?

Comment: Thanks, I may consider doing this if a simpler solution doesn't present itself

Answer (score 0):

this is the method that I use, matches your need but less typing and brain cell consumption:

`curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz | tar -xzvf -`

(btw, you can add `-d dependencies=lombok`
when the dependency you want is listed on [starter](https://start.spring.io/) like lombok.)

And then, in `vim pom.xml`, delete whatever parent and modify everything between dependencies.
you just need to fill in group, artifact and version.

Finally, `mvn package`. It starts to download...