# what maven command can I use to download jar package from Nexus private server?

Tags: maven, jar, nexus

I deployed many maven project on nexus. Now I want to use a maven command to download a jar package and its dependencies by giving its coordinate. I have the following solution:

1. create a maven project and add the jar (I want to download) to POM as dependency.
2. using command `mvn compile` to the new maven project. maven will download the target jar and its dependencies to local repository.
3. create a shell script to cope the jar and its dependencies to specific folder from local repository.

There must have better solution to download jar from nexus directly without creating new maven project. Just like a command: `mvn download -DgroupId:ArtifactId:Version`. 
Do you know the similar command or some plugins have the goal.

Answer (score 6):

Use the dependency plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html
See [How do I download a Maven artifact at the command line without using dependency:get or maven-download-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262861/how-do-i-download-a-maven-artifact-at-the-command-line-without-using-dependency)

Comment: my pleasure. please accept it as the correct answer